# Implications of generating public keys for incremental private keys?

Tags: public-key

Let us consider a hypothetical situation.

What would be the implications if there is a method by which one can calculate the public keys for incremental private keys, with the help of only the public key?

For instance, one is given a public key only. (that public key has the private key as 1001) and he is asked to calculate the public key of the next private key or the 10th one or any incremental private key after the given public key. So he can calculate the public key of the private key 1002 or 1011 only with the help of the public key of 1001.

Comment: What the question hypothesizes is trivial with DSA, ECDSA, EdDSA, and more generally anything which public key is obtained by scalar multiplication of a public generator in a public group by the private key.

Comment: If they know the private key corresponding to the first public key, it's trivial, since they can just increment the private key and calculate the corresponding public keys. If they don't know the private key, they can't get any useful information about it from the public key (or the system would be insecure), and can't calculate what the "subsequent" public keys would be.